# Axis2 versions per Tomcat

Tags: apache, web-services, tomcat, web-applications, apache-axis

I am new to Axis2 and I like to know the supported Axis2 versions for :

- Tomcat 6
- Tomcat 7
- Tomcat 8

If it's not too much to ask, I also want **the source of the information**.

Many Thanks.

**EDIT :** These are the known Axis2 versions :

- 1.6.1
- 1.6.2
- 1.6.3
- 1.6.4
- 1.7.0
- 1.7.1
- 1.7.2
- 1.7.3

Source : http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/release-notes/1.6.1.html

What I need to know, which of these versions is for Tomcat 6, Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must compare 2 JDK version, servlet versions of

- Apache Tomcat
- Apache Axis2

http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/installationguide.html  (current version).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't find the corresponding servlet version for every Axis2 version in the second link you posted, can you please assist ?

Comment: If you have decision rights, For simple, let's choose latest stack: Apache Tomcat 8.0.36, Apache Axis2 version 1.7.3, JDK version 1.8 update 102. You must look up Axis2 **release notes** ( http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/release-notes/1.7.3.html ), this is a consuming-time task.

Comment: OK let's change the question a little bit : if I want to upgrade Axis2 to more recent version, should I also upgrade Tomcat ?

Comment: Before your update idea, What are your current `Apache Axis2` and `Apache Tomcat` versions?

Comment: Axis2 version : 1.6.2

Tomcat version : 7.0.55

Comment: I need more information, what is your JDK/ JRE version?

Comment: My JDK/ JRE : 1.7 (Java 7)

Comment: Apache Axis2 1.6.2 released in 17th April 2012. Tomcat 7.0.x require JavaSE 6 or later. If you apply continuos integration methodology, you merely deploy to CI server then see comparability result. But you don't apply CI methodology, you must accept **risk when try to upgrade**. Follow version numbering rules, Tomcat 7.x and Tomcat 8.x is significantly different. With JDK, because backward-compatibility (1.7 to 1.8), there are no problem.

Reference: 
https://github.com/apache/axis2-java/releases/tag/v1.6.2  
   and 
http://mirrors.viethosting.vn/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.70/README.html